# Magento 2 - Class doesn't Exists when compiling

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, plugin, class

I tried to create a simple plugin (magento 2.4.3-p1) :

But when I run the compiler, I have the following error :

> In PluginListGenerator.php line 326:
> Plugin class Fseb\ModuleA\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product doesn't exist

Here is the code:

**app\code\Fseb\ModuleA\registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Fseb_ModuleA',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app\code\Fseb\ModuleA\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Fseb_ModuleA" setup_version="1.1.0"/>
</config>
```

**app\code\Fseb\ModuleA\etc\frontend\di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="Fseb_ModuleA" type="Fseb\ModuleA\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app\code\Fseb\ModuleA\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product.php**

```
class Product
{
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        $title = 'lalalala';
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Could you help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Plugin, the namespace is missing.

Here is the code you should have :

```php
<?php
namespace Fseb\ModuleA\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Product
{
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        $title = 'lalalala';
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Also, as told by Matt H., you should fix the `config` node in your `di.xml` file.

Note : For more informations about Plugins, here is the official doc :
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

On your di.xml change the config to:
`<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">`

Then run setup:upgrade before setup:di:compile

Everything else seems right.